# IntelliJ - External library recognized but build fails

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've been recently trying to build a Java project which looks as follows:

```
./someProject
./libForSomeProject
```

in `./someProject`, I'm importing an interface and a class from `./libForSomeProject`. I learned recently that in IntelliJ, one can make `./someProject` aware of the `./libForSomeProject` by adding it as an external library (project structure -> libraries etc.). Indeed, when I do this, the IDE seems to recognize the classes from `./libForSomeProject`. However, when trying to build, it says that it could not find the `libForSomeProject`. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, as the classes seem to get recognized - if I'm not importing the `./libForSomeProject`, they are "red" and marked as unknown (as they should be), so something is definitely being imported, but the build fails. Anyone seen something similar?

Thanks

Comment: are you using a dependency management system? I've seen it happen when the classes are present in one scope, but are needed in another.

Comment: Yes, maven (if that's what you mean)? Would that imply I should somehow add that to pom.xml too?

Comment: Well, it depends. IF you told IntelliJ to rely on the MAVEN definitions, then only these matters. If you defined your project layout twice, within maven AND within intellij, then different story (and btw: you should absolutely not have two project definitions ... make sure maven is your primary source).

Comment: You could put your library into the _local_ maven repository, and only use a maven dependency.

Comment: Could you please point me to an example of this? So, basically just having it in the pom.xml as a dependency?

Comment: @sdgawerzswer do you know what adding it as a dependency in your pom file does?

Comment: Not 100% I'm doing this right, could you point me to an example of this (note that the lib is not a jar but some classes)

Comment: Though not certain, I've an idea that 'raw' class files are not supported in Maven. You could roll them into a jar and add a local repo though

Comment: Hey, was able to solve this by adding the dependency manually to the pom.xml (maven is not exactly compatible with how IntelliJ adds libraries). Also, the dependency had some custom flags I was not aware of. So, @JoopEggen, you could post an answer, in the end it was a convoluted version of this :)

Comment: "the lib is not a jar, but some classes". then it's not really a lib; where did these "some classes" come from?

Comment: There was an "archetype" with "lib" in name, assumed this is also a library (just not .jar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can put a library into the local maven repository, and then only use a maven dependency instead of adding it to IntelliJ IDEA's libraries. Which is an other mechanism than maven's.

For every IDE one must distinguish on its "native" conceived build/library handling and the way a build infrastructure like maven or gradle handle libraries aka dependencies.